# Identifying specific table after mysql UNION

Tags: php, mysqli, union

I have this code

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, dateAdded as date FROM table1 UNION SELECT id, dateSeen as date FROM table2 ORDER BY date DESC");
While($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $sql['id'];
}
```

Please how can i detect from which table an `$id` originated. For instance if outputted I get something like this

```
1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

So how can I know from which table each `id` came from because I have other informations I want to retrieve from each separate table using a function, Example

```
$title = table_query('title', $table, $id);
$name = table_query('name', $table, $id);
```

Comment: With a union you can't know which select the row came from. You can however add a constant field for which you can identify the table from which it came. 'SELECT "table1" as fromtable, id, dateAdded as date FROM table1 UNION SELECT "table2", id, dateSeen as date FROM table2 ORDER BY date DESC'. It can also be a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this. What you can do is add data in your query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id, dateAdded as date, 'table1' AS tblname FROM table1 UNION SELECT id, dateSeen as date, 'table2' AS tblname FROM table2 ORDER BY date DESC");
while($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $sql['id'];
    $tbl = $sql['tblname']; // this variable will store the name of the table.
}
```

For each query, the string `table1` | `table2` will be added as the 3rd column, and you can use it in your code.